# Powershell - Hashtable update key value

Tags: powershell, hashtable

In a CSV automation i get a hashtable as outpout at the end.

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                      
----                           -----                                                                                                      
GetTruckLocations              {GetTruckLocations, 101, 7}                                                                              
GetYardLocations               {GetYardLocations, 234, 1}
```

If the same keys coming again while going line by line in the csv.

```
GetTruckLocations              {GetTruckLocations, 423, 2}                                                                              
GetYardLocations               {GetYardLocations, 313, 6}
```

I need to update the key values like below.

```
GetTruckLocations              {GetTruckLocations, (101+423)/2, 7+2}                                                                              
GetYardLocations               {GetYardLocations, (423+313)/2, 1+6}

GetTruckLocations              {GetTruckLocations, 262, 9}                                                                              
GetYardLocations               {GetYardLocations, 368, 7}
```

Somebody please tell me how to access the key value and update it..

Thanks..

Comment: Both the `$primary` and `$secondary` variables represent Hashtables, not arrays. To me it is quite unclear what you want the `$secondary` to look like. Please edit your answer and add the desired result to it. Also, you need to put the `!` INSIDE the brackets like this: `if (!$secondary.ContainsKey($scenarioname)) {`

Comment: Try ($secondary[$scenarioname]).TotalCount += $primary.TotalCount

Comment: Theo I am sorry for the way i explained the issue. I just modified it. Thank you..

Comment: @f6a4 Not working. .Thank you